# Prove that index of $K$ in $G$ is less than or equal to $n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H\le G$ has finite index $n$ in $G$. Prove that there is a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ contained in $H$ such that $|G : K|\le n!$.

It is well known that the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$ is $\displaystyle\bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$. Will this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ given by $g\cdot (xH)=gxH$. This gives you a homomorphism $G\to S_n$ whose kernel is a normal subgroup contained in $H$ and having index equal to the size of the image, hence a divisor of $n!$.